# IOS 6 view controller incorrect width / bounds - landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

My app utilizes both landscape mode and portrait mode and the user can switch between the two at will.

When a view controller is presented by a parent view controller that is in **portrait orientation**, the opened view controller will have the **correct width & frame**.

However, if the parent view controller is in **landscape mode**, then on IOS6 (it works correctly on IOS7), the child view controller will be **too large** and actually a little too short also when it is presented.

Note this is not because the values are reported incorrectly since [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] reports the same values regardless of the orientation the child controller is loaded in.

Any ideas on how to fix this / why this is happening?  Any idea on how to force the IOS6 versions to behave like IOS7 is now behaving natively?  Many thanks!!!

Edit::
Here's how the vc's are presented:

AppDelegate

```
Launch1 *launch1 =[[Launch1 alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = launcher;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Launch1 class

```
Search *search = [[Search alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:search animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Search class

```
//load list_container
views = [[Search_custom_views alloc] initWithControllerContext:self];
[self.view addSubview:views];
```

Search_custom_views UIView extension:

```
- (id)initWithControllerContext:(UIViewController*)contextstart {

    //set size of the screen
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    self = [super initWithFrame:screenRect];

    if (self) {
     ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was a tough one.  I load all my views programmatically.  They basically are UIView subclasses that correspond to each view controller.  For some reason, when an IOS6 view controller is opened from a parent view controller in landscape mode, the child view controller's bounds are not immediately passed on the child vc's UIView subclasses (if you just use addSubview in the viewDidLoad method of the controller--it is not enough).  IOS7 does not have this problem.

The fix for IOS6 for me was doing the following in the viewDidLoad method of the child view controller:

```
//add view subclass to view controller
[self.view addSubview:views];

//reset bounds & refresh layout for IOS6
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7) {
    views.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [views layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 likes it when you call `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` instead of `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` because the applicationFrame property is not consistently calculated between different versions of iOS, while bounds is.

It should be backwards compatible, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
- (CGRect)filterBankFrameForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {//using bounds here instead of applicationFrame for iOS7 compatibility
        //Handle landscape orientation
        filterBankFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, k_filterBankOffsetFromTop, appFrame.size.height, k_filterBankHeight);
    }
    else {
        //Handle portrait orientation
        filterBankFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, k_filterBankOffsetFromTop, appFrame.size.width, k_filterBankHeight);
    }
    return filterBankFrame;
}
```

and simply flip the height and width values as needed (since bounds will always be in "portrait" orientation)

Using `bounds` should give you the consistency you need for identical behavior across iOS versions and device sizes.

***Updating in response to OP's updated code***

One approach I'd recommend you at least consider is wiring up these views in InterfaceBuilder and using AutoLayout to worry about the rotations for you. It has the added benefit of gracefully handling ALL of the different screen sizes available too, so that can be nice too.

Still, creating and managing it all in code is perfectly acceptable too, and may be the right call for your situation. If so, you'll want to override a few of the rotation handling methods of `UIViewController`. Probably most or all of these:

```
– shouldAutorotate
– supportedInterfaceOrientations
– preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
- didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation
```

at a minimum the first one and the last two.

To avoid being tied to one orientation only at launch, it is a common design pattern (citation needed) to write a method like the one I posted above, and then utilize it from both `viewDidLoad` as well as from the `willRotate / didRotate` class methods.

When calling during viewDidLoad, you do something like this:

```
_filterBank.collectionView.frame = [self filterBankFrameForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
```

which uses the `statusBarOrientation` property to launch correctly in either landscape or portrait.

The `willRotate / didRotate` methods both give you a parameter you can pass to your frame generating method.

Your method gives you the right frame size, then it's all up to you to pass down this info and manipulate your view hierarchy accordingly. It's easier than it sounds...

(in your case, it looks like `launcher` would implement the methods, then coordinate the adjustments to `launch1` and then down to `search` and finally to `Search_custom_views`)

(**last side note, you'll make more friends here by choosing `SearchCustomViews` instead of `Search_custom_views`)

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything.  I think it is because the parent view controller is in landscape view when the child is initialized.  Maybe IOS7 auto-rotates the parent back to portrait before displaying the child and then rotates them both back?  Can't figure out what's happening here.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post some code from both of the view controllers? Especially how they are created and linked to each other (nib file or in code?) and if either of them implement any of the rotation specific methods in [the UIViewController class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I just added the code in my question above.  The view controllers are all able to rotate freely, but don't implement the rotation methods--it is just specified in build settings.  Thanks again!

Comment: I updated the original answer with some more explanation for you Phyllis. If you're looking for more extensive explanations, I highly recommend [Matt Neuburg's guides](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-iOS-6-Matt-Neuburg/dp/1449365760)